# Formio angular stop loading button and show error

Tags: angular, formio

i handle submit event by outside functions like `(submit)=“my-submit.emit($event)` 
but i dont know how to stop loading button when success or failed and show error message inside form. can you help me, thank.
My code bellow

```
in html template
  <formio [form]="formDescription" (submit)="submit.emit($event)" "" [submission]="submission"></formio>
in typescript 
export class FormioViewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() formDescription;
  @Input() submission:any;

  @Output() submit :EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Please add some code to your question or create a stackblitz demo

Comment: what is that error message?

Comment: error when i process failed i want to show in formio